# MsgSetRequest - Can I throw too much data at it?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, quickbooks, qbfc

I'm working on a C# library project that will process transactions between SQL and QuickBooks Enterprise, keeping both data stores in sync. This is great and all, but the initial sync is going to be a fairly large set of transactions. Once the initial sync is complete, transactions will sync as needed for the remainder of the life of the product.

At this point, I'm fairly familiar with the SDK using QBFC, as well as all of the various resources and sample code available via the OSR, the ZOMBIE project by Paul Keister (thanks, Paul!) and others. All of these resources have been a huge help. But one thing I haven't come across yet is whether there is a limit or substantial or deadly performance cost associated with large amounts of data via a single Message Set Request. As I understand it, the database on QuickBooks' end is just a SQL database as well, but I don't want to make any assumptions.

Again, I just need to hit this hard once, so I don't want to engineer a separate solution to do the import. This also affords me an opportunity to test a copy of live data against my library, logs and all.

For what it's worth, this is my first ever post on Stack, so feel free to educate me on posting here if I've steered off course in any way. Thanks.

Comment: Synergration has some QuickBooks tools that might be able to expedite this process. Give OpenSync (or CoreObjX/DB) a look.  http://synergration.com/software

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I found that in a network environment (as opposed to everything happening on 1 box) it's better to have a larger MsgSetRequest as opposed to a smaller one. Of course everything has its limits, and maybe I just never hit it. I don't remember exactly how big the request set was, but it was big. The performance improvement was easily 10 to 1 or better.

If I was you, I'd build some kind of iteration into my design from the beginning (to iterate through your SQL data set). Start with a big number that will do it all at once, and if that breaks just scale it back until you find something that works.

I know this answer doesn't have the detail you're looking for, but hopefully it will help.

Comment: It definitely helps. I'll revisit this post with some results when the time comes. Thanks for sharing.